# Connected components of real invertible symmetric matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology, matrices

Let $S$ be the set of all real invertible symmetric $n\times n$ matrices.

By Sylvester's law, we get the partition $S= \cup_{k=0}^n S_k$ where $S_k$ is the set of all matrices of the type $P J_k P^{T}$ where $P$ is an invertible real matrix and $J_k=diag(1,\cdots,1,-1,\cdots,-1)$ (the first $k$ components are $1$ and the next $n-k$ components are $-1$).

Are the $S_k$ the connected components of $S$ ? (and if yes, why ?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that you can replace the matrix $P$ by a matrix with positive determinant. The space $GL_n^+(\mathbb{R})$ is path-connected. Therefore the spaces $S_k$ are path-connected. Moreover, the signature of a matrix is an invariant under transformations of the type $S \mapsto PSP^T$. Therefore the $S_k$ are the path components.

Comment: Why can we replace $P$ with a matrix with determinant 1 ?

Comment: My bad, what I should have said is that you can replace $P$ by a matrix with positive determinant, because you can replace $P$ by $-P$. I have edited this in the answer.

Comment: Thank you, I see why the $S_k$ are connected. I don't see why the fact that that the signature is invariant by the transformation $S\to PSP^T$ implies that the $S_k$ are the path components. I'd be happy for an explanation of this.

Comment: For this, you need to observe that the map $S \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$ given by the signature is continuous.

Comment: Yes, that's the thing, i don't see why that the signature map is continuous, is it a well-known fact?

Comment: The signature can be expressed as the number of positive eigenvalues minus the number of negative ones. Each of the eigenvalues depends continuously on the matrix. so the signature does.